# FileNotFoundException even if file is exist and path is properly supplied

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a RCP Project wherein I am setting image to view and It was working fine but once I changed the folder name from 'icons' to 'logIcons' from eclipse , tool throws exception 'FileNotFoundException'. Previously path was 'icons\error.png' and after changing folder name I changed to 'logIcons\error.png' too but image doesn't load when workbench loads. Many time I have done this kind of folder changes and many time it throws exception but don't how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must list all the folders that you want included in a plugin in the `build.properties` file. You have probably forgotten to do this for `logIcons`. Open the build.properties editor and check the folders you need.

This is easy to forget as the code will work OK when you test run it from within Eclipse but will fail when you build the RCP.

You must also use the correct methods of accessing resources in a plugin. The `FileLocator` class is the appropriate class to use.

In testing you should always have `-clean` and `-clearPersistedState` specified in the Run Configuration to make sure that cached data is rebuilt to be current on each run.

Comment: I have already listed 'logIcons' folder in build.properties. I am accessing resources via plugin.xml. I mean I am setting image to view from plugin.xml like <view class="com.logs.errorLogs" icon="logIcons\error.png" ..>

Comment: Then you haven't given us enough information. Show us the actual code that is trying to access the images.

Comment: I am accessing resources via plugin.xml. I mean I am setting image to view from plugin.xml like <view class="com.logs.errorLogs" icon="logIcons\error.png" ..> </view>. Application still throws error for java.io.FileNotFoundException : /icons/error.png even if 'icons/ folder is not exist anymore.

Comment: For testing make sure you are specifying `-clean` and `-clearPersistedState` in the Run Configuration to be sure to pick up the new locations.

Comment: RIght. That was the problem. Because app was taking older reference. Now cache is removed and resolved the issue. Thanks Greg.